# Generating json schema from a json with restangular

Tags: angularjs, scala, playframework

I have an input text in a form where I put a json, what I want is to generate a json schema from this input after a button click, can anyone guide me, how can I generate my schema what component should I use?

Comment: What did you already tried? Could you post some input and output examples?

Comment: i need something like this(http://jsonschema.net/#/),i need this part in my project with angular;thank you so much for any help

Answer (score 0):

In your view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="json_input" ng-click="generateJsonSchema()" />
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.generateJsonSchema = function() {
    var json_object = JSON.parse($scope.json_input)
    console.log(json_object)
}
```

Comment: i need to generate a schema json from a json, i don't search to parse to json